# can't execute mpiexec command through ssh

Tags: ssh, parallel-processing, paramiko, mpiexec

I have multiple VMs and I want to execute parallel processing using these VMs. I wrote a program that uses ssh to connect to the VMs. The mpiexec command should be executed through ssh on the VMs. 
But, that is not happening and I don't even get an error message

```
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())    
ssh.connect(ips_in_file[0]) # connecting to the VM
cmd1="mpiexec --wdir /export/validation_files/ -f /export/validation_files/freeVMs.txt -n "+str(numVMs)+" python mulpar_new.py "+ s+" cmd>>matrix_result.txt"
ssh.exec_command(cmd1)
```

I don't think mpiexec is executing
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: first, can you `ssh` by `ssh` itself like `ssh user@server` or by any means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include path to mpiexec, you can get it using the following command on VM

```
    which mpiexec
```

Instead of

```
   cmd1="mpiexec --wdir /export/validation_files/ -f /export/validation_files/freeVMs.txt -n "+str(numVMs)+" python mulpar_new.py "+ s+" cmd>>matrix_result.txt"
```

Use

```
   cmd1="<path to mpiexec>mpiexec --wdir /export/validation_files/ -f /export/validation_files/freeVMs.txt -n "+str(numVMs)+" python mulpar_new.py "+ s+" cmd>>matrix_result.txt"
```